# What criteria are used to compare feature-based classification techniques?

Tags: linear-model, k-nearest-neighbour, gaussian-mixture-distribution

When comparing feature-based classification techniques, what characteristics about the different processes should be considered?

I'm comparing different classification techniques to try to figure out what should be considered when selecting a classification technique.  In particular, I'm comparing the following:

- Linear classifiers
- K nearest neighbors
- Gaussian mixture models
- Bayesian networks
- Rule induction / decision trees

---

**Edit**

When I am considering which classifier I should use, I think about the following:

- Training time
- Classification time
- Classification accuracy
- Generates a probability vs. giving a class

What other things should be considered?

Comment: Some of these are supervised, while others are unsupervised. I don't think you can't compare the two in general. Among supervised methods (linear classifier, tree, nets etc), you can look at precision recall on test data set, cross-validation, etc.

Comment: @JohnJiang Thanks for your response.  I'm not that familiar with the differences between supervised and unsupervised, so I wasn't aware that you could only use some of these techniques if you didn't know what class they really belonged to....

Comment: The difference is actually very simple: for supervised learning you need a label (either continuous or discrete), unsupervised you don't. Sometimes you can pretend your data has no label and run unsupervised learning to engineer some artificial features for further supervised training, this can be useful for dimension reduction, or de-correlation of features.